# React, keep value on Picker while changing Input data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Picker with 3 possible values: A, B and Other.

If "Other" is picked, then I need to render an `Input` (only when Other is picked).

The value of that `Input` will be the value of my Item picked.

So
if I pick A, value should be A.
if I pick B, value should be B
if I pick Other, value should be the value of the Input text.

But when I start to write, the label of the selected Item changes. My code (just the important parts):

```
import { Picker } from 'react-native';

const subjects = [
  { label: 'A' value: 'A' },
  { label: 'B', value: 'B' },
  { label: 'Other', value: 'Other' }
];


const [state, setState] = useState({
    subjectSelected: ''
  });

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Picker
          mode='dropdown'
          selectedValue={subject}
          onValueChange={ value => {
            setState({ ...state, subjectSelected: value });
            changeBeneficiarySubject(value);
          }}
        >
          {subjects.map((sub, key) => (
            <Picker.Item
              key={key}
              label={sub.label}
              value={sub.value}
            />
          ))}
        </Picker>

        { state.subjectSelected === 'Other' && (
          <Input
            value={subject}
            onChangeText={ text => {
              changeBeneficiarySubject(text);
            }}
          />
        )
        }
    </ScrollView>
  );
```

`subject` comes from redux, it's well updated with the action

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ transaction }) => ({subject: transaction.receiver.subject});
const mapDispatchToProps = { changeBeneficiarySubject };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeneficiaryExtraInfo);
```

`changeBeneficiarySubject()`.
`Picker` is a React Native component, it's just a Select Picker, nothing fancy.
I don't know how can I do what I need, I'm kinda confused.

Comment: My guess is you're using `useState` in a wrong way; you're supposed to have a separate call for each variable. `const [subjectSelected, setSubjectSelected] = useState('A');` would be the first state line, next you need something like `const [text, setText] = useState('');` for the input text. You're also using `subject` as the value for both the Picker and the Input (and this seems to be the error causing this issue)

Comment: Thanks man! I was very stucked, I follow your observations and now I could finally change. I will post my code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Now I have another state for the Input text:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  subjectSelected: '',
  subjectOther: ''
});
```

And also, previous the next step, I replace the value on redux with the local state that I need:

```
const handleNext = () => {
  if (state.subjectSelected === 'Other') {
    changeBeneficiarySubject(state.subjectOther);
  }
  navigation.navigate('ConfirmTransaction');
};
```

And the Inputs has this onChangeText:

```
onChangeText={ text => {
  setState({ ...state, subjectOther: text });
  changeBeneficiarySubject(text);
}}
```